# How does AWS implement getbucketlocation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was wondering how getbucketlocation work. Is there a centralized store to save all the bucket-location mappings? Buckets created in Regions launched before March 20, 2019 are reachable via the https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com So If I have a bucket, then I use https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxx to access the bucket then it will query the centralized mapping store for the region then route my request to correct region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a centralized database in us-east-1 and all the other regions have replicas of it.  This is used for the [GET bucket location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html) API call as well as List Buckets.

But this isn't used for request routing.

Request routing is a simple system -- the database is DNS.  There's a DNS record automatically created for every single bucket -- a CNAME to an S3 endpoint in the bucket's region.

There's also a `*.s3.amazonaws.com` DNS wildcard that points to us-east-1... so these hostnames work immediately when the new bucket is in us-east-1.  Otherwise there's a delay until the specific bucket record is created, overriding the wildcard, and requests send to that endpoint will arrive at us-east-1, which will respond with an HTTP redirect to an appropriate regional endpoint for the bucket.

Why they might have stopped doing this for new regions is presumably related to scaling considerations, and the fact that it's no longer as useful as it once was.  The `${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com` URL style became largely irrelevant when mandatory Signature Version 4 authentication became the rule for regions launched in 2014 and later, because you can't generate a valid Sig V4 URL without knowing the target region of the request.  Signature V2 signing didn't require the region to be known to the code generating a signature.

S3 also didn't historically have consistent hostnames for regional endpoints.  For example, in us-west-2, the regional endpoints used to be `${bucket}.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` but in us-east-2, the regional endpoints have always been `${bucket}.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`... did you spot the difference?  After `s3` there was a `-` rather than a `.` so constructing a regional URL also required knowledge of the random rules for different regions.  Even more random was that region-specific endpoints for us-east-1 were actually `${bucket}.s3-external-1.amazonaws.com` unless, of course, you had a reason to use `${bucket}.s3-external-2.amazonaws.com`  (There was a legacy reason for this -- it made sense at the time, but it was a long time ago.)

To their credit, they fixed this so that all regions now support `${bucket}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com` and yet (also to their credit) the old URLs also still work in older regions, even though standardization is now in place.